# how to get a list size em VB .NET?

Tags: list, listbox, size, vb.net-2010

I need to display a list on a ListBox component in VB .NET.

```
// params is a string representing a path, empty means root folder
params.itemsPath = ""

// resp is a response object, here it is a String[]
resp = myAPI.browseTags(params)

Dim listSize As Integer
listSize = resp.itemsList.GetLength

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To listSize
    ListBox1.Items.Add(resp.itemsList(i).itemName)
Next
```

I'm not familiar with VB .NET and this should be a very simple issue, but I need help!

The code 'resp.itemsList.GetLength' is underlined in blue and there's a tooltip that reads:

"Argument not specified for parameter 'dimension' of 'Public Function GetLength(dimension As Integer) As Integer".

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GetLength(0)`

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> An example of GetLength is
>   GetLength(0), which returns the number
>   of elements in the first dimension of
>   the Array.

Answer (score 12):

there is, call function Count():

```
List.Count
```